# Accessing a remote database through SSH tunnel

Tags: python, mysql, database, pymysql, ssh-tunnel

I want to access a remote database through SSH tunnel.

```
server = SSHTunnelForwarder(
    ('172.17.9.125', 22),
    ssh_password="123456",
    ssh_username="root",
    remote_bind_address=('127.0.0.1', 3306))

server.start()

database = pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1',
                           port=3306,
                           user='root',
                           passwd='root')

try:
    dbsql = "CREATE DATABASE TestDB"  # Create database
except Exception as e:
    print("Error: ", e)
database.cursor().execute(dbsql)

global db, cursor
db = pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1', port=3306, user='root', passwd='root', db='TestDB')

cursor = db.cursor()
print("Connected to MySQL database")

f = open("testdb.sql")  # Execute .sql file, creating data tables
full_sql = f.read()
sql_commands = full_sql.split(';')[:-1]
try:
    for sql_command in sql_commands:
        if sql_command is not None:
            cursor.execute(sql_command)
        else:
            print("Null")
    print("Created database")
except Exception as e:
    print("Error: ", e)
```

I want to create a new database named as "TESTDB" on this remote server, 172.17.9.125.

But I get this database created in localhost. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have a database running, your `3306` port is used in that so won't be able to bind.

Solution : bind it to some other port and try to connect to that.

You can bind to another address using `local_bind_address=('0.0.0.0', 1234)` (this will be your target local address/port to which it will be bound) in your arguments to `SSHTunnelForwarder`.

So your connection TunnelForwarder should be something like this

```
server = SSHTunnelForwarder(
    ('172.17.9.125', 22),
    ssh_password="123456",
    ssh_username="root",
    local_bind_address=('0.0.0.0', 1234),
    remote_bind_address=('127.0.0.1', 3306))
```

And now connection will be made to `port 1234`

```
database = pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1',
                           port=1234,
                           user='root',
                           passwd='root')


db = pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1', port=1234, user='root', passwd='root', db='TestDB')
```

Comment: Then it gives a connection refused error as following: "ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it"

Comment: Try to turn off your MySQL, and then try to connect via your code. Then does it run?

Comment: Actually I have missed the line "  local_bind_address=('0.0.0.0', 1234),". And now it works as I needed. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I tried for so long to connect to a remote database without specifying a local_bind_address. Then the engine would actually connect to my local running mysql instance on port 3306 instead of the remote one. Thank you!!!